# Functions default named parameters issue

Tags: powershell-4.0

If I call the function without any parameters the default values work

When I call a function with named parameters and I leave one of them blank I get a error...  Any way to correct this?

Here is the function

```bsh
function foo {
  Param(
    [string]$a,
    [string]$b = "bar",
    [bool]$c = $false
  )

  Write-Host "a:", $a, "; b:", $b, "; c:", $c
}
```

```bsh
foo "hello"
```

returns `a: hello ; b: bar ; c: False`.

```bsh
foo -a test -b test -c $true
```

returns `a: test ; b: test ; c: True`.

```bsh
foo -a test -b test -c
```

throws an error:

> foo : Missing an argument for parameter 'c'. Specify a parameter of type 
>   'System.Boolean' and try again.

Answer (score 1):

A parameter's default value is assigned when you omit the parameter entirely. If you provide the parameter but omit the value `$null` is passed.

Instead of using boolean parameters it's usually better to use switches:

```
function foo {  
  Param(
    [string]$a,
    [string]$b = "bar",
    [Switch][bool]$c
  )

  Write-Host "a: $a`nb: $b`nc: $c"
}
```

The value of a switch is automatically `$false` when omitted and `$true` when present.

```
PS C:\> foo -a test -b test -c
a: test
b: test
c: True
PS C:\> foo -a test -b test
a: test
b: test
c: False
```

You can also explicitly pass a value like this:

```
PS C:\> foo -a test -b test -c:$true
a: test
b: test
c: True
PS C:\> foo -a test -b test -c:$false
a: test
b: test
c: False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [bool] as the type for $c. If you are doing so PowerShell expects a value by calling:

```
foo -a test -b test -c
```

Thats because you are telling PowerShell: Don't use the declared Default, i want to overwrite the default, but you're not telling which value PowerShell should use instead of the default.

I think what you are looking for is a [switch] for your function. 
Try:

```
function foo {  
    param([string] $a, [string]$b = "bar", [switch] $c) 

    Write-Host "a:", $a, "; b:", $b, "; c:", $c 
} 

foo "hello" -c
```

The result will be:

```
a: hello ; b: bar ; c: True
```

If not using the -c switch $c will be $false.

More Information can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878252(v=vs.85).aspx --> Switch Parameters